# how to automatically reorder boxplot that has already computed mean, min, max, q25, and q95 value?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to reorder the boxplot in increasing value but the boxplot was made by manually inputting the information of min, max, mean, q0.25 and q0.95

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(p = c("a", "b", "c"), min=c(1,20,3), max=c(34,60,50), 
                  q50=c(15,40,20), q25=c(11,30,13), q95=c(20,47,35))
dat %>% ggplot(aes(x=p, ymin=min, 
                  ymax=max, 
                  lower=q25,
                  middle=q50, 
                  upper=q95)) +
  geom_boxplot(stat="identity")
```

if the code is being run, we can see that b has a higher value than c and a, but I want to reorder them into b,c, and a (or in increasing/either decreasing order) automatically because in real data I have 195 value of x.

I checked the 'reorder' function but it seems it needs the x is not a factor/chr (my x in here is 'p' which is a chr/string).

any help will be greatly appreciated.

thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Using `reorder` you could reorder by the median like so:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  p = c("a", "b", "c"), min = c(1, 20, 3), max = c(34, 60, 50),
  q50 = c(15, 40, 20), q25 = c(11, 30, 13), q95 = c(20, 47, 35)
)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(
  x = reorder(p, q50, decreasing = TRUE), ymin = min,
  ymax = max,
  lower = q25,
  middle = q50,
  upper = q95
)) +
  geom_boxplot(stat = "identity")
```

[image]